# Squirrel won't run (ClassNotFoundException : TextureLookAndFeel )

Tags: java, squirrel-sql

At work we had a java update, and then I tried opening my Squirrel today, and I get this error :

> 2018-08-01 16:20:04,936 [AWT-EventQueue-1] ERROR
>   net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.plugins.laf.jtattoo.JTattooLafData  -
>   Unable to load LAF class
>   (com.jtattoo.plaf.texture.TextureLookAndFeel):com.jtattoo.plaf.texture.TextureLookAndFeel
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.jtattoo.plaf.texture.TextureLookAndFeel   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.util.MyURLClassLoader.findClass(MyURLClassLoader.java:209)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
>   net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.plugins.laf.jtattoo.JTattooLafData.putClass(JTattooLafData.java:82)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.plugins.laf.jtattoo.JTattooLafData.initLafMap(JTattooLafData.java:65)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.plugins.laf.jtattoo.JTattooLafData.(JTattooLafData.java:49)    at
>   net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.plugins.laf.jtattoo.JTattooLookAndFeelController.(JTattooLookAndFeelController.java:92)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.plugins.laf.LAFRegister.installLookAndFeelControllers(LAFRegister.java:461)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.plugins.laf.LAFRegister.(LAFRegister.java:141)

I tried deleting the 'LAF' directory in my user settings, but I still get the error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my computer and now it works! :)